# Is it possible to to use Azure AD V1 V2 token token using MSAL in Microservices?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, adal

I m working with azure add and have more then 10 microservices.
have existing implementation with ADAL library.

now I have started converting my microservice to use MSAL.
as we know ADAL use V1 token and MSDL will start using V2.

will that work both at same time cos if I start converting my projects to use
MSAL it will happen gradually.

any one know will MSDL and ADL token will work same time with my all microservice ?
as I will start with one of microservice to use MSDL ..
any thought.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified how you are validating your token etc but in general yes, an application/service can trust tokens of multiple types and from multiple issuers without any problem as long as you tell it to.

Comment: as i m mention i m using ADAL for my services and with .net application i m using middleware to verify but now problem is  will token created by V2 endpoint or by MSDL by existing microservice which are using ADAL will authenticate it?

Comment: sorry I dont understand the issue

Comment: i m using adal in my microservice and creating token with V1 version
refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens
now i m converting my application to use MSAL so now token will be generated by V2 end point. so my one of microservice use v2 and other v1 so will this token so will my V1 end point will allow V2 token ?

Comment: as long as you are using properties available in both token versions yes it will work

Comment: so does it mean V1 token or V2 token will work with my all microservices though some microservices have ADAL implementation and other have MSAL implementation ? is this correct